# Is it possible to use die/echo etc without {?

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

So, Well I was wondering, Is it possible to do this;

```
if($pro == true)
    echo "He's";
    echo "a";
    echo "pro.";
```

Or do I need to use { }
? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Some (or maybe most) people (and so do I) think you should always use the `{ }`, also when there is only one statement between the brackets. Check out [this link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your intentions. With your code

```
if($pro == true)
    echo "He's";
    echo "a";
    echo "pro.";
```

The result (if $pro is true) will be:

```
He'sapro.
```

If $pro is false it will be

```
apro.
```

If you don't want that output on false, please add the braces.

```
if($pro == true) {
    echo "He's ";
    echo "a ";
    echo "pro.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

questioner I think it's simple if else structure we all know from inception of coding.

After executing first line after IF block without bracket( '{' ), rest will be executed as it is.

> if(1==1)
>      echo "Hi!";
>      echo "How are you?";
>
> So the output of the above is: ***Hi! How are you?***
>   Both lines are returned.

Now if you want to separate out output then enclose else block,

> if(1==1) { echo "Hi!"; } else { echo "How are you?"; }
>
> So the output of the above is: ***Hi!***

**#SpongePablo** has truly explained well.